# How to set MCRYPT path back to MAMP Pro

Tags: php, laravel

I've done installing MCRPYT at MAMP Pro with PHP 7.2 and I was able to run my old project Laravel 4.2.

Here are the list of what I have in my MAMP PHP.ini

`extension=mcrypt.so`

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/"
```

But when I run `which mcrypt` it default to `/usr/local/bin/mcrypt` which I thought it should be under MAMP Pro.

The reason why I am asking this is because, I wanted to upgrade my project Laravel 4.2 to 5.0.
And here's the problem when I tried installing fresh Laravel 5.0

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.8 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.6 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.5 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.35 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.34 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.33 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.32 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.31 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.29 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.28 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.27 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.26 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.25 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.24 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.23 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.22 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.21 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.20 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.2 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.19 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.18 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.17 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.15 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.14 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.13 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.12 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.11 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.10 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework 5.0.30 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.30, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33, v5.0.34, v5.0.35, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/conf/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Note

If you wanted to know how I made to run Laravel 4.2 using PHP 7.2 with MCrypt. Check this link.

https://medium.com/@tomgrohl/making-laravel-4-2-work-with-php-7-2-e9149a9428c3

Comment: pretty sure mcrypt has been removed since PHP 7.2 ... also do you really want to be using Laravel 5.0? maybe it is possible you could install a fresh copy of Laravel 6 and move things over to it

Comment: im running experiment as of now since the project i have is currently using laravel 4.2 and checking if upgrading it to 5.0 will be easy for me, though this wasn't as expected. I follow this guide https://medium.com/@tomgrohl/making-laravel-4-2-work-with-php-7-2-e9149a9428c3 and the project is running fine for laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

If php version lower than 7.1:

Install and enable mcrypt:

```sh
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

Try to find your php.ini  and open it.

```sh
vim php.ini
```

Put one line in to this file

```php
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Restart php and apache.

Else

Try to upgrade your laravel version greater than 5.5.
like:

```
     "laravel/framework": "5.5.*"
```

Because the framework that you install  is 5.0, it require `PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7`.
See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements

Comment: I don't think there is going to be a mcrypt package for PHP >= 7.2.0

Comment: @lagbox You're right. After searching php.net reference, it said that many (all) mcrypt functions have been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0.

Comment: I am both running mcrypt at my osx. one with the osx and the other is at mamp pro. the problem is, i forgot how to point it back the mcrypt to mamp pro, 2nd i misplaced the website where there's the guide for it. if ever, please see my note at my question for my reference.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns So, do upgrade your pecl?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes. it is upgraded.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns Please try to upgrade your laravel framework greater than 5.5